# Tensorflow Image Processing Matching Image, Bounding Box and Labels

Tags: tensorflow, image-preprocessing

I have three folders with millions of records each:
Images (has jpg images)
Box (has xml files with bounding box coordinates, one xml file per image)
Label (has txt files with the label of the image, one txt file per image)

how can I match all three files in a tensorflow dataset pipeline?

I want to crop the image by the bounding box coordinates and match the output to get an image, label pair.